# How to override `turbo_frame_tag` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo, turbo-frames

I'm using Ruby on Rails 7 with the [Turbo Rails](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/tree/main) gem, which provides the [turbo_frame_tag](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/app/helpers/turbo/frames_helper.rb) method.

I would like to add default html data attributes to all the `<turbo-frame>` tags that are generated through `turbo_frame_tag`. That is, given the default data attribute to add is `data-custom="value"`, I would like to generate the following HTML each time I use `turbo_frame_tag`:

```
<turbo-frame id="..." data-custom="value">...</turbo-frame>
```

How can I make that in an initializer?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this... first define your custom attributes in an initializer:

```rb
# config/initializers/custom_turbo_frame_attributes.rb
CustomTurboFrameAttributes = {foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux'}
```

Then override the Rails turbo_frame_tag view helper to include your custom attributes. I did this by including the following in app/helpers/application_helper.rb. There's probably a cleaner way, but I didn't take the time to find it!

```rb
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module Turbo
  module FramesHelper
    def turbo_frame_tag(*ids, src: nil, target: nil, **attributes, &block)
      id = ids.map { |id| id.respond_to?(:to_key) ? ActionView::RecordIdentifier.dom_id(id) : id }.join("_")
      src = url_for(src) if src.present?
      attributes.merge!(CustomTurboFrameAttributes) # bingo! here are your custom attributes
      tag.turbo_frame(**attributes.merge(src: src, target: target).compact, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

This is just the Turbo view helper copied and changed to include your custom attributes.

An alternative, if you can live with it, is to define a helper called `custom_turbo_frame_tag`, and add in your attributes (defined as above). This approach then calls the standard ActionView turbo_frame_tag helper, and so it might work better in case future Rails versions change the built-in helper.

```rb
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module Turbo
  module FramesHelper
    def custom_turbo_frame_tag(*ids, src: nil, target: nil, **attributes, &block)
      attributes.merge!(CustomTurboFrameAttributes)
      turbo_frame_tag(ids, src: src, target: target, **attributes, &block)
    end
  end
end
```